# Stopping a push segue from going until told to move forward - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have an `IBOutlet` on a button that will be used as a login button. It gets sent to a function for that button and I want to do my processing in there and once completed push the `viewcontroller` forward.

I have the login button linked already to the view controller to move forward. How do I pause that push segue from moving forward until the application does its processing and than tells it to move forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of linking the button directly to the next view controller, create a general segue from the one `UIViewController` to the next `UIViewController` and specify an identifier for that segue, so that within the .m of you view controller, you can use `performSegueWithIdentifier:` when you're ready to perform the segue.

To connect the view controllers in this way, click on the black bar below the first `UIViewController` and control + drag from the yellow button to the second `UIViewController`.

Then to perform the segue use:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TheViewControllerIdentifier" sender:self];
```

within your button's IBAction method if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

Do not link directly the button on the storyboard to the next viewController, link it to an `IBAction` instead, where you put your login code and when login is done you push the next viewController like this
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:theNewViewController];`
If you don´t know how to create the `newViewController` try:
MyViewController newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theIdentifier"]
And don't forget to add `theIdentifier` to the new viewController in the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method in your controller

`- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender`

In this method you can do your custom processing and indicate if you want the segue to be performed or not